# How are Dspace MetsGenerator result integrated back in the DRI?

Tags: dspace

My fundamental problem is to be able to insert RDFA in my final HTML Page. Hence i need to work with the metadata as they serve as the source of the text that will be tag with html Tags containing RDFa.

I would like to know how can I get fine control of that part. I believe this would require me to understand deeply how the Mets are generated.

I am seeking guidance on how to to customize the tags around generate for the metadata.

I would need to add more information in the mets such as RDFa types, and add it to the html attribute around the metadata text that is displayed.

What should I look at for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just change the XSL in your theme to include the RDFa, in a similar way as the simple item view is generated? You aren't telling us what DSpace version / theme you are using, but here is how (in DSpace 5.2 / Mirage 2) eg the abstract is shown on an item page: https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5.2/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/item-view.xsl#L229

Comment: Sorry i am using the version 1.8.x. I'll check your link

Comment: A Proper way to do that would be to interact with a TripleStore to get the rdfa types of the metadata values e.g person, topics, etc... whatever the triple store returns. But it is true that we could infer it ourself, if we have a unique type of things per metadata field type; such as stipulating that dc_subject only takes topics, but not people. In other words, a person can not be a the subject of a publication. This is somewhat limiting.

Comment: To avoid that, one has to add the type to the mets generation. That is, the TripleStore interaction would only happen in the backend at the mets generation and then in the xsl all information would be there to format as desire.

Comment: Ah right, so you're wanting to change the actual mets.xml that is generated? I didn't catch that from your question, you might like to edit it to give more details, such as: what do you want the mets.xml to look like, what do you want the resulting HTML to look like, what information do you have in your triple store. Also, have you looked at the rdf add-on for DSpace?

Answer (score 0):

I think the class that you need to look at is ItemAdapter -- it gets called by the DSpaceMETSGenerator and actually creates the mets.xml file. https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/objectmanager/ItemAdapter.java